# Firebase Cloud Function ends before .get() finishes

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get() all users with a certain field value in Firestore. Then putting them in a list to be able to send an email to all of them. But for some reason the function keeps ending (according to the logs) before the emails are all found.

I also get the following error:
Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

This is my code:

```
exports.stuurJuisteTekenaarUpdate =
functions.firestore.document('opdrachten/{opdrachtId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
 const nieuweOpdracht = snap.data()
 console.log(nieuweOpdracht.disciplines);
 let tekenaarsRef = db.collection('tekenaars');
 let alleTekenaars = tekenaarsRef.where('disciplines', '==', nieuweOpdracht.disciplines).get().then(snapshot => {
      const promises = [];
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
       const p = doc.data().email
       console.log(p);
       promises.push(p)
      })
    return Promise.all(promises)
  })
  //return null
});
```

Using the final 'return null' silences the warning but does not solve the problem of the function ending before receiving the email addresses.

Once this is fixed I want to run the following code:

```
     .then(emailAdressen => {
      // getting dest email by query string
      const dest = 'vaneijkchris@gmail.com';
      const mailOptions = {
       from: 'CAD-Tekenaar.com <info@cad-tekenaar.com>',
       //to: emailAdressen,
       bcc: emailAdressen,
       subject: `Er is een nieuw tekenproject aangemeld - CDT.${nieuweOpdracht.opdrachtnummerjaar}.${nieuweOpdracht.opdrachtnummer}`, // email subject
       html: `
        <p style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: 600;">NIEUW TEKENPROJECT AANGEMELD</p>

            <div style="height: 2px;background-color: #144b89; width: 100%;margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>


<p style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: 600;">Beste tekenaar,</p>
              <p style="font-size: 16px;">Er is vandaag een nieuwe opdracht binnengekomen binnen jouw vakgebied.<br>Als je interesse hebt wil je mij een mail sturen?<br></p>
              <p style="font-size: 16px;"><br>Discipline: ${nieuweOpdracht.disciplines}</p>
              <p style="font-size: 16px;">Tekenprogramma: ${nieuweOpdracht.tekenprogramma}</p>\
              <p style="font-size: 16px;">Opdrachtomschrijving:<br> ${nieuweOpdracht.omschrijving}</p>\
            <br>
            <p>Interesse in deze opdracht? Reageer dan op deze email.</p>


`
       // email content in HTML
      };

      // returning result
      return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
       if(erro){
        return res.send(erro.toString());
       }
       return Promise.all(res.send('Sended'));
      });

      return Promise.all()

     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
       response.status(500).send(error)
     })
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning a promise from the top level of the function callback.  This is required so that Cloud Functions knows when all the async work is complete and it's safe to clean up.  Try this instead:

```
 return tekenaarsRef.where('disciplines', '==', nieuweOpdracht.disciplines).get().then(snapshot => {
      const promises = [];
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
       const p = doc.data().email
       console.log(p);
       promises.push(p)
      })
    return Promise.all(promises)
  })
```

Please [read the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more information.